# caluculating error or parents error in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

```
a = 1200
b = 2200
c = 28276

t = 7
de = 7
dx = 12

func = (a*t)de+(b*t)dx-c

print(func)
```

but after compiling this, some error occurred.

File "", line 9
func = (a*t)de+(b*t)dx-c
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I really dont understand about parents.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for: `func = (a*t)*de+(b*t)*dx-c`. The simplest way to perform multiplication in Python is by using the asterisk (*). You may also refer to arithmetic operators found in this [documentation](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/#arithmetic-operators)

Comment: *"You cannot multiply variables or numbers in Python without the asterisks (\*)"* - [Oh yeah?](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69Ew0xBLz4@tzQnPl7DXFPz/38A)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! Will rephrase my statement.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping my leaning.